# get all the std::string's or first word's before character '='

Tags: c++, string, stdstring

I wanted to retrieve all the values/words before '='

```
Ex: 
    A = my first variable, I wanted to get all the strings;
    var2 = I wanted to get this variable also;
    var3 = jcdksjfckjdsckjdscjkdsbckjdsncjsjd;
```

Now I wanted to retrieve all the variables `(A, var2, var3)` from the above text (c++ std::string).

**Update: One possible way is**

```
vector<string> myClass::getVariablesFromDescription(string f_description)
{
    vector<string> l_variables;

    stringstream l_desc;
    l_desc << f_description;

    string l_temp;
    string l_prvStr = string();

    for(int i=0; l_desc >> l_temp ; i++ )
    {
        if(l_temp == string("="))
        {
            l_variables.push_back(l_prvStr);
        }

        l_prvStr = l_temp;
    }

    return l_variables;
}
```

Comment: can do C style string parsing (char by char), But looking if some ready made function or a way available for std::string.

Comment: Take a look at [`std::string`'s interface](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), there are member functions that can make it a bit cleaner than your writing the parsing code yourself. (specifically, `find` and `substr` should come in handy)

Comment: I looked at them before only, we can get index's of '=' with find, But then how i can i find word before to =  ???   any hint

Comment: I thinks some people they just down vote without reading and understanding, can see my ans down.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new string, start copying the original byte-by-byte there and stop when you detect a '='.

```
string example = "var69 = asdfghjkl";
string var_name;

for(int i=0; i<example.size(); i++)
{
    if(example[i] == '=') break;
    var_name += example[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet, but you asked for a hint.

find returns a position of where the = sign is.  You also know you started at 0.  Then you can get the string from 0 to position and just copy that out.

Comment: what about other variables, its continus text & there is no delimiters.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, in the question I replied to, he just wanted all the data from position 0 to the first = sign.  I gave him exactly that.  Find defaults to position 0 without having to specify it.  I wrote the code at home and it worked as expected, I just didn't remember to email it to myself.  Then again, he wanted a hint, so doing it all wouldn't be much of a hint either.  As I said, I cannot comment, therefore only way to give a hint is this.